# what happens after useState setter after component is unmounted?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
const Comp = ({}) {
  const [state, set_state] = useState();
}
```

What happens to `set_state` when `Comp` is unmounted?

Specifically, will `Boolean(set_state)` return `true` or `false`?

Comment: `set_state` is a function (which is never falsy) and there's no way that will change. It's `const` as well. So I'm not sure what you did expect to happen?

Comment: I was expecting that after the component is unmounted, `set_state` would be undefined

Comment: Why would the variable change? Sure, the variable and the function will get garbage-collected when nothing references them any more (which typically happens when the component unmounts), but then you would no longer be running code that accesses them (like `Boolean(set_state)`). What is your [actual question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?